# Exporting global variables to a valid PHP file for reproducibility

Tags: php, debugging, webserver

I have a web application running on PHP. It sometimes has bugs, and I'd like to
be able to reproduce specific requests locally through the CLI SAPI. The way I
imagined doing it was something like this:

```
<?php
// index.php
if (!empty($_GET["export_for_debug"]) && DEBUG_MODE) {
    file_put_contents("request.dat", serialize(get_defined_vars()));
}

// resume normal execution
```

This isn't for any public facing feature, it's just to allow reproducible
requests for debugging with phpdbg or similar.

However, I'm having trouble extracting the request variables into the current
global ones.

```
<?php
// test_request.php

// get the request variables
$vars = unserialize(file_get_contents("request.dat"));

// this doesn't work
extract($vars);

// neither does this
foreach ($vars as $key => $val) {
    $$key = $val;
}
```

tl;dr: How do I extract an array that looks like this:

```
array("_SERVER" => array("foo" => "bar"))
```

Into the current scope?

---

Edit:

I got it. You can overwrite the globals, but it seems like the code needs to be
eval'd. After a little bit of trial and error, here's what I got:

```
<?php

// get the request variables
$vars = unserialize(file_get_contents("request.dat"));

foreach ($vars as $key => $val) {
    eval("\${$key} = \$val;");
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Suhosin does prevent overwriting the superglobals for instance. If you only probed the variable contents using your debugger, then it might also not reflect the final value state ($_SERVER is uncommonly modified at runtime).

Comment: Good to know, thanks @mario. Either way, it looks like it `$_SERVER` can't be overwritten except by `eval`.

Comment: I've tested in phpdbg v0.4.0: `extract(array("_SERVER" => array("foo" => "bar")))` does work, if it used in `.phpdbginit` script file. Command in phpdbg console `ev $_SERVER` prints: `Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `phpdbg` console:

1) Create file named `.phpdbginit` into the working directory from which you call `phpdbg`. File contents:

```
<:
extract(array("_SERVER" => array("foo" => "bar")));
:>
```

2) Start debugging console `phpdbg -e PATH/TO/SCRIPT/NAME.php`. For example `phpdbg -e index.php`

3) Test if it works using command `ev $_SERVER`

For me with php 5.6.12 and phpdbg v0.4.0, it prints:

```
root@host:/var/www/html# cat .phpdbginit
<:
extract(array("_SERVER" => array("foo" => "bar")));
:>
root@host:/var/www/html# phpdbg -e index.php
[Welcome to phpdbg, the interactive PHP debugger, v0.4.0]
To get help using phpdbg type "help" and press enter
[Please report bugs to <http://github.com/krakjoe/phpdbg/issues>]
[Attempting compilation of /var/www/html/index.php]
[Success]
phpdbg> ev $_SERVER
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```